# Mongodump on Gridfs is killing the host IOs

Tags: mongodb, io

I'm trying to make a mongodump from our production mongodb while the production is running.

We have three production instances, one regular mongodb, one with very few gb of data on gridfs, one with a larger amount of data on gridfs.
All mongodb instances are running in version 2.4.9 on a ubuntu 10.04 virtual server.

I use a mongodump command to export the bases to another server.

Unfortunately our machines are virtually hosted in a "low performances" datacenter (vmware based) so when I try to export the large gridfs db, the disk IO hits 100% (and 50% of the cpu starts waiting for IO too).

This has a very negative impact on the production applicatiosn because db access time is excessively increased, making the applications unusable.

I'm looking for a way to regulate the mongodump so the export goes slower but cooler on the hardware ressources allowing better performances for the applications to run.

Has anyone had a similar scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to throttle a read - and that's all `mongodump` is doing, a single read that walks the _id index for the databases you are dumping and then writes out the data in BSON format.  The IO impact you are seeing is because it has to page data into memory to read it (this is the case with all reads).

In terms of suggestions, I can think of a couple of things that might help:

1. Point `mongodump` at a secondary instead of the primary
2. Take a secondary out of the set (shut it down) and use that to get a copy of the data

The first option will isolate the impact to the secondary, and it may then fall behind in replication and have to catch up, but unless you are using secondary reads there will be no impact to your application.

If you are using secondary reads, then you will see the impact to the application.  That's where the second option comes in - it will mean getting a slightly "stale" version of the data (but that will be the case as soon as you write anything after the `mongodump` anyway) but by shutting it down and taking it out of the set you guarantee no impact to your application.  You can also simply take the data files and use them directly - no need for `mongodump` (this is usually significantly faster).

Comment: actually "ionice" is able to throttle a read. Though i lack experience in mongodb we use ionice values for having an ~80GB postgres DB backuped without significant increase in page response or DB reads, writes of the DB are a bit slower during backup time but thats because of the way we do the backup.

see http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice for the manual of ionice

Comment: But, since all the requests are coming from the same binary (mongod) you can't use ionice - the mongodump uses a regular query just like anything else and that is then serviced by mongod, so it's not competing with another process.  You can use mongodump to access files directly (and hence ionice would work on it) but you have to shut down the mongod to be able to do that anyway, so nothing gained.

Comment: @"Adam C" i see, thank you for the info.
Can you distinguish the querys somehow?
In Postgres one is theoretically able to ionice a specific query when having the backend PID, not 100% as valid as a normal file operation, but still better than nothing.

Comment: Not at the moment, unless you use a node specifically for that purpose - you could have a secondary and tag it as "backup", the others as "prod" for example and have the backup queries only hit that node.  You could even run more than one process on the host, make one of the them your designated backup node and then ionice that process, but for a single existing process there is no way to target specific queries within that process from a system level (that I know of).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, We're not using a replica on that base. It's try to fit one in the coming week and I'll tell you how it goes

Comment: I would assume that mongodump is pulling the data with an unfiltered find(), and iterating through the cursor results. If that is so, couldn't mongodump limit how quickly it moves through the cursor i.e. roughly throttle to x mb/sec? My understanding of typical firehose cursor behavior is that the server application will only read and send data as fast as the client can pull it off of the network. I don't see such a config option in mongodump currently, but I would guess it would be possible to add.